# Jungle disk and Xubuntu : junglediskdesktop keeps spawning additional icons

Tags: linux, ubuntu-10.10, linux-distro

I have a non-modified install of Xubuntu (xfce4) on my eee pc 901. For backups, I use jungle disk which comes with a system tray application called junglediskdesktop. junglediskdesktop keeps spawning new icons in my system tray part of the panel, especially when the icon is updated (from idle to work-in-progress). Does anyone else have this problem?

the reason why I think this is xfce4-related is because junglediskdesktop stays with one icon in the system tray in both Ubuntu (gnome) and Lubuntu (lxde) on the same computer.

Any suggestions?

regards,
Peter

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by upgrading xfce to xfce 4.8, I guess it was some kind of bug in the old version.

regards,
Peter